# CPUid showing fluctuating CAS latency and speed

Tags: memory

Dell Inspiron 7460. 
Changing between 1064Mhz 15-15-15-35 and 665Mhz 10-10-10-28

Is this normal/okay?  I've tried different sticks, and different slots and the same result.

Comment: If you have two different CAS timings, then both memory modules, are not running the slowest CAS timing.  The difference in those CAS timings are negligible, if there is a difference detectable outside of a memory benchmark, I would be shocked.  It is not clear what your actual problem is.

Comment: If you have 2 different RAM modules, they won't run in dual anyway.

Comment: Most modern PCs will run them in dual. (4+4 and the remaining 4 in single.). 

@Ramhound I should have also mentioned that in concert with these fluctuations, the frequency is also changing... It's going back and forth between 665Mhz 10-10-10-28 and 1064Mhz 15-15-15-35... I mean, while the laptop is on CPUid is showing going back and forth. 

So my actual problem is that I don't know if this is normal...Some type of RAM frequency stepping?

I have now tested the original 4GB alone and the 8GB alone and in different slots and it's the same situation.

Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Reset BIOS to factory settings. All normal now. I guess when added the RAM something got quirked in BIOS.